# How to get collapsed box to appear on smaller resolutions

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if you could tell me how to get a collapsable box to appear on on a website using javascript?

What I want on the website is to resize the screen (to like a mobile for example) and it replaces the nav bar with a drop down box that has to be clicked on.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance to all!

```css
#navLocation {
 position:relative;
 float: right;
 top: 55;
 right: 125;
 font-size: 155%;
}
```

```html
<div id="navLocation">

<a id="container" id="navLocation" href="index.html">home</a>&nbsp; <a href="about.html">about</a>&nbsp; <a href="projects.html">projects</a>&nbsp; <a href="news.html">news</a>&nbsp; <a href="contact.html">contact</a>

</div>
```

Comment: You should take a look at a simple framework such as bootstrap. It's a pretty straightforward mobile friendly library that may be just what you are looking for. You can take a look at all the different components they have here: https://getbootstrap.com/components/

Comment: it is possible but what code have you seen like this and what code have you tried? edit your question and hit CTRL + M and paste all of your code into the box.

Comment: I've edited the post and inserted the code to what I have currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m5wf2sc5/2/)

```css
    .navbar-inverse {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top:10px; 
    float: right;
    border: none;
    margin-right: 10px;

    border-radius: 0px;
}


.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #000000;
    border: none;
}


.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:focus, .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: 000000;
}



ul li{
 font-size: 20px;
}


ul li a{ 
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #000000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
          </button>
          
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 2 </a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

is this the same that you want?

hope this helps.

Comment: Not quite but thank you - I've edited my post with my current code if that helps.

Comment: @Benjaminbl12.. I have updated my answer. this is what you want as your output?

Answer (score 0):

I have made an example for you. Please have a look.

> ```
> `https://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimince/yrashdfm/`
> ```

ups. I have forgotten to add jquery library. You need to add jquery library.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/ibrahimince/qntz5w3u/
```